# Symbols become boxes after reset

Tags: fonts, htc-explorer

I recently factory resetted my HTC Explorer, but all the special characters have become squares ([] for unrecognized symbols).

Even the HTC Sense Calculator widget's decimal button has changed and the arrow on StackExchange site when browsing on the device is showing the same squares.

I have tried:

- factory reset three times
- reboot,
- battery pull,
- SIM removal and microSD card removal.

Please help!